postfix smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols
My server is rejecting smtp connections I have the following in master.cf:
-o smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols=!SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
Can anyone tell me if this line could be the cause of the error

I don't think so. You should look at the mail log for more details. Normally it should be at /var/log/mail.log.

TLS handshaking: SSL_accept() failed: error:0A00018C:SSL routines::version too low

In my configuration (default for Ubuntu 24.04) smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = >=TLSv1 smtp_tls_protocols = >=TLSv1 smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = >=TLSv1 smtpd_tls_protocols = >=TLSv1 

routines::sslv3 alert bad certificate
